# Working with csv file in python3 programme shows "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, csv

[typeError with csv file in python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNTD.png)I tried to write a python3 programme that writes and edit data in csv file,but it is showing TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not'str'
screenshot of the output in the terminal is attached.I don't know what this means and what is wrong.Someone help me fix it.the code is below:

```
import csv
import datetime
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def get_length(file_path):
    with open("data.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    #some csv file data.csv is created in the same directory
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader_list = list(reader)
        return len(reader_list)

def append_data(file_path, name, email, amount):
    fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent', 'date']
    #the number of rows?
    next_id = get_length(file_path)
    with open(file_path, "a") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerow({
                "id": next_id,
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "sent": "",
                "amount": amount,
                "date": datetime.datetime.now()
            })

#append_data("data.csv", "some name", "address@mail.com", 123.456)

def edit_data(edit_id=None, email=None, amount=None, sent=None):
    filename = "data.csv"
    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile, temp_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent', 'date']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        #print(row['id'] == 4)
        if edit_id is not None:
            if int(row['id']) == int(edit_id):
                row['amount'] = amount
                row['sent'] = sent
        elif email is not None and edit_id is None:
            if str(row['email']) == str(email):
                row['amount'] = amount
                row['sent'] = sent
        else:
            pass
        writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move(temp_file.name, filename)
    return True
return False
```

## edit_data(8, 9992.32, "")

edit_data(email='address@mail.com', amount=19.90, sent='10')

Comment: On Python 3 when using `csv` readers and writers you need to open your file `open("data.csv", "r", newline="")`. Using `rb` is compatible with Python 2.x only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Python 3 when using csv readers and writers you need to open your file `open("data.csv", "r", newline="")`. Using `rb` is compatible with Python 2.x only. You also need to setup similar settings for your `NamedTemporaryFile`.

The following should help:

```
import csv
import datetime
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

fieldnames = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'amount', 'sent', 'date']

def edit_data(edit_id=None, email=None, amount=None, sent=None):
    filename = "data.csv"

    with open(filename, "r", newline="") as csvfile, \
        NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode="w", newline="") as temp_file:

        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in reader:
            #print(row['id'] == 4)
            if edit_id is not None:
                if int(row['id']) == int(edit_id):
                    row['amount'] = amount
                    row['sent'] = sent
            elif email is not None and edit_id is None:
                if str(row['email']) == str(email):
                    row['amount'] = amount
                    row['sent'] = sent
            else:
                pass
            writer.writerow(row)

    shutil.move(temp_file.name, filename)

edit_data(email='address@mail.com', amount=19.90, sent='10')
```